# Global page in smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I am new in the smartface and I saw [Faruk's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Am6QYNXzbw) yesterday. In the video I saw a page name of which is "Global" contains some variables created automatically when one write some text in the text area of an object. But I could not find a page like that (Global). How can I open that page in order to declare some variables?

I get some errors on debugging as I cannot declare variables that I named them writting their names without quotes in the text attribute of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in the ~/[*your_project_name*]_data/Script/ folder.

By the way, if you use version 4.3.x, the file name is Global_Smartface.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the Global page in Smartface from the "Script Editor".

When you press "Scripts", script files will be listed. Find "Global" in this list and press on it. Global.Smartface.js will be opened.

If you want more information about using script editor, you should see the link below : 
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/general/script-editor/